# Is there really a need to use CacheVirtualItems on a virtual ListView if ListViewItems are fixed and already on a List<T>?

Tags: c#, listview, design-patterns

I am wondering what the actual design purpose of the CacheVirtualItems event is for when using a ListView in virtualmode. So far most of the examples I can find online are for purposes like when clicking Next on a list of data in an online page and what not.

If I have a fixed List of ListViewItems that are loaded manually by the user and the items will always be kept in the collection no matter what, should I even be using the cache event at all? It's not like I will be generating new ListViewItems per scroll. Should I be fine design pattern-wise without handling the event on a fixed collection of ListViewItems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you are holding the entire list in memory then there is no need to respond to `CacheVirtualItems`. It is merely a hint that you can use to improve efficiency.

The `CacheVirtualItemsEventArgs` argument supplies an index range, allowing you to efficiently load just that range into memory in a single operation. This avoids having either to load the entire list or to load individual items one at a time.